# How to select two columns together distinctly in no particular order?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to select two columns together distinctly in no particular order in MySQL.

For example, the given table is below -

```
col1 col2 col3
--------------
a    b    val1
a    c    val2
b    a    val1
b    c    val3
c    a    val2
c    b    val3
```

I need to distinctly select **col1** and **col2** in no particular order.

```
col1 = a AND col2 = b
```

is equivalent to

```
col1 = b AND col2 = a
```

in my case, as col3 value will be same for both combinations of col1 and col2.

Expected result is below -

```
col1 col2 col3
--------------
a    b    val1
a    c    val2
b    c    val3
```

I want to eliminate duplicates actually.

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry @forpas , it was a typo. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you an alternative and probably better solution in terms of performance tuning, You may try below query without using window functions -

```
SELECT * FROM mytable M1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable M2
                  WHERE M1.col1 = M2.col2
                  AND M1.col2 = M2.col1
                  AND M2.col1 < M2.col2)
```

Since it uses exists clause, It will perform faster than above query. [Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w7EvkX2nAj8QqzMARwXx3q/0) is the demo for both the queries.

Comment: Yes, you're right ankit. I have a table with 3M+ rows.
@blackbishop 's solution is taking about 36.5 seconds whereas yous taking 0.0033 seconds. Thank you.

Comment: Whattttt???? Even I am shocked after seeing this much performance difference. I guess this must be happening due to index usage by this query.

Answer (score 2):

Use `greatest` and `least` functions to create groups:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM (
      SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2) ORDER BY least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2)) AS rn
      FROM mytable
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2aac56be80fe2b35a7ecb022e81d2055).